# android-remove title of submenu item on right side option menu?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, submenu, optionmenu

Here is my menu xml code for menu and submenu,
When i press in menu that contain submenu, there is submenu autometic show title of there parent menu i want to remove it.
Here is screen for it's 
[image: Screen shot for main menu]
   [image: Screen shot submenu that want,]

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_call"
    android:icon="@drawable/call_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/menu_search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_attach"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_attachment"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/menu_comment"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuScheduleSmS"
    android:title="@string/menu_schedule_sms" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menuMore"
    android:title="@string/menu_more">

    <menu>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuBlockContact"
            android:title="@string/menu_block_contact" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuClearChat"
            android:title="@string/menu_clear_chat" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuEmailChat"
            android:title="@string/menu_email_chat" />

    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Why won't you get rid of that submenu from your `xml`?

Comment: means..?@azizbekian

Comment: Why don't you remove `<item>` tag with id `menuMore`? You'll end up with [this](https://pastebin.com/sDF4xpBn) `xml`.

Comment: no am not exact want to this type but, there is menu with submenu more that has new popopmenu and that include title of parent menu i wan't to remove it.

Comment: please check update new screen shot @azizbekian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/* remove header of submenu */
MenuItem menuMore = menu.findItem(R.id.menuMore);
if (menuMore != null) {
    menuMore.getSubMenu().clearHeader();
}
```